# How do you compile an OpenGL program on Ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, opengl

When I try to compile [the first example](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/abgr.c) on [this page](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html) using:

```
cc -o abgr abgr.c -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lXext -lX11 -lm
```

I get an error message saying:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXmu
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is "`lXmu`"?  How do I get this to compile?

Comment: -lXmu tells the linker to include the libXmu library. Technically there should be no need at all to add -lXext, -lX11, since those are pulled in by GLUT implicitly. libXmu is seldomly used and AFAIK GLUT doesn't depend on it at all, so you may just omit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may have to install libxmu-dev

try:

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev libxmu6
```

Answer (score 4):

Try installing libxmu-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to learn by [this](http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/get_opengl_setup_linux/video.php) . For me , it is better to start off with some video. Good luck with the learning! kiddo! haha